# Air vent squeaks while car in on position

Tags: ac, kia

My kia rondo 07 if I have key in on position but not started I turn air on and it squeaks like old door hinge is  that not normal or a problem

Comment: Are you saying there isn't any noise when the car is running?

Answer (score 2):

The only real differance between your vehicles electrical system with the engine on or off is made by the alternator. Running on battery, your system voltage will be lower then when the engine drives the alternator. With the alternator running, supplying the air fan with a higher voltage, the air fan will run a little faster and is the losing the conditions to allow it to squeak by causing the fan to be better 'balanced' in its operation.